# ssis oledb source deadlock in source query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a data flow, oledb source and oledb destination (both are SQL Server). In source, there are two tables A and B, A has 4M rows and B has 6M rows. They all have 30+ columns. When I do the query, I select 30 columns from A left join B where a.date > '2020-01-01'. it will return 50K rows. the query last 9 -10 seconds. Sometimes, I got error

> Transaction (Process ID 75) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Even I did the query directly on the source server, I also could get

> Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

but not as frequent as on the SSIS

Is that because they are transaction tables, user could do some update at the same time?

How to avoid it. Like in SSIS, if fail can SSIS wait for 5 second and reran it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS doesn't know anything about scheduling. Typically, that is done through SQL Agent in which you can specify retry on failure values.

The root of your question is why am I getting these deadlocks. You are asking for data and your request is preventing a more important query from completing. Since your query is less important, it gets snuffed out so the database as a system can remain operational.

Your question identifies that you are querying against transactional tables and yes, the day-to-day operation of the system is what is likely killing your queries. The deadlock graph in the default extended event would reveal precisely what happened (ask your DBAs for help).

As David Browne points out, you likely need to look at using a different isolation level to allow your read queries to operate on data while concurrent activity inserts/deletes/updates data. This tends to be decision points the business units that you are generating ETL for can provide guidance. Maybe working with "dirty" data is acceptable. If so, add `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` to your query. 
If not, then you need to look at the query plans being generated and optimize them. Maybe the left join could be reworked as an Exists if you're only using it to test whether a condition exists. Perhaps there's implicit conversion going on all over the place. Or statistics are out of date. Or a covering index could be created. Lots of options here, but the key takeaway is make the query go faster so there's less resource contention.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [row-versioning isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation or SNAPSHOT isolation to prevent your SSIS source query from acquiring locks on the data it reads.

Comment: if I add ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON; before my query, will effect the source table?